# How to run node js in my linux based server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, server

I'm finding an answer for couple weeks. My question is that, is there any process to run node js in my linux based server. I know that there is amazon or digital ocean which have in build system which run node js in their own but is there any process by which node js will run in my own linux based server?

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: You just need to install nodejs using npm or similar. Write your application to listen to a port (3000 as an example) and make your router forward that port to the linux server

Comment: You of course can install node.js on your own linux server.  What problems have you had installing on linux?  https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Answer (score 1):

1) You need install node.js. Better to do this [with NVM](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps), then you will able to change Node.js version very easy. Also current long term support Node.js version is 6.9.1, so use this one.

2) You need some process runner for better stability in your backend. My offer is to use [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io).